# How do I get R to calculate a negative IRR scenario?

Tags: r, negative-number, irr

I have been doing stochastic cash flow modeling. In some of these scenarios, IRR is negative (cash flows out exceed cash flows in over time). R seems to hate this. I get a uniroot error. I have used the FinCal package irr function, and I even tried to write my own uniroot IRR formula. It's important that any formula solves for both positive and negative IRR scenarios.

Any suggestions or ideas? Is there an R package that handles this, or a simple uniroot formula?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I think i figured out a way to make this work: uniroot(npv,c(-.2,1),cf=xd)$root where xd is the cash flows.

Comment: Share your solution with the SO community. :)

Comment: How do I do that? Also, I just got the creators of the FinCal package to add irr2 which handles negative irr - but is slower than traditional irr

Comment: I am also relatively new to SO. Doesn't it give you a textbox to put your answer in? They give you a preview of your answer before you submit and a little tutorial on how to add links and whatnot.

Comment: Well - maybe I spoke prematurely, the uniroot solution above works for simple cash flows but not the complex ones

Answer (score 0):

i ended up writing my own code (based upon irr from FinCal) where errors are ignored. I also changed the range to incorporate negative numbers when uniroot is looking for a solution. FYI - errors happen because a value is out of range or because there could be two solutions. Use irr4 to solve.

```
    irr3<-function (cf) 
    {  n <- length(cf)
    subcf <- cf[2:n]
    uniroot(function(r) -1 * pv.uneven(r, subcf) + cf[1], lower = -.2, upper =      .2, tol = .000001)$root}

   irr4<-function (x) {
   out<-tryCatch(irr3(x),error= function(e) NULL)
   return(out)}
```

Comment: Updated version:irrplus<-function (cf) 
{  n <- length(cf)
  subcf <- cf[2:n]
uniroot(function(r) -1 * pv.uneven(r, subcf) + cf[1], lower = 0, upper = 2, tol = .000001)$root}

irrneg<-function (cf) 
{  n <- length(cf)
subcf <- cf[2:n]
uniroot(function(r) -1 * pv.uneven(r, subcf) + cf[1], lower = -.5, upper = 0, tol = .000001)$root}

irr4<-function (x) {
  out<-tryCatch(irrplus(x),error= function(e)
  { out2<-tryCatch(irrneg(x),error= function(f) NULL)
  return(out2)})
  return(out)}